# How to prevent auto switch to website when send otp firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

How to use Firebase Authentication to send OTP to phone without show website when click send. I have tried anyway but it always switch to website when i click button Send code.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times while implementing dependencies like:

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
```

the above window pops-up in the browser.

Here, is a way to resolve it successfully.

1. In the Google Cloud Console, enable the [Android DeviceCheck API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com) for your project. The default Firebase API Key will be used, and needs to be allowed to access the DeviceCheck API.

[image]

2. If you haven't yet specified your app's SHA-256 fingerprint, do so from the Settings Page of the Firebase console. Refer to Authenticating Your Client for details on how to get your app's SHA-256 fingerprint.

[image]